# RabbitMQ Shovel Ack-Mode

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I am using RabbitMQ shovel between two clusters, and I am seeking answers to the following:

- what is the actual difference between on-confirm and on-publish modes
  if the destination queue is durable and the messages there are persisted?
- I want the message removed from the source queue when the destination broker successfully writes it in the destination queue, not waiting for the consumer to ack it in the destination queue, Just once it's written in the destination queue it gets removed from the source queue, So what mode should I use?

I tried both of them and can't choose the proper one